# Wordpress admin dashboard disabled after migration to another server and https

Tags: php, wordpress, https, admin

Disclaimer: I don't now WordPress on any level, so if I provided with not enough of details or you need some extra information please let me know.

Hello, 
I have migrated with some 'legacy' WordPress project to new server and Https . And faced with following problem:

1) To hide wp-adming and wp-login, there was installed plugin WPS hide login. e.g. it leads to `example.com/blog/hiddenurl/`;

2) After it was moved to new server and https was enabled - it seems to became broken as doesn't redirect me to admin dashboard.

3) When I am trying to access wp-admin directly it gives me `This has been disabled` message.

I suppose that this might be ralated to https, as I have already applied hack from [here](https://snippets.webaware.com.au/snippets/wordpress-is_ssl-doesnt-work-behind-some-load-balancers/) .

Besides this problem seems to be already raised before few times, e.g. [on forum](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/this-has-been-disabled-while-logged-in/) . But there no helpful answers, expect disable some plugin and there are no this plugin installed. The only thing which seems to be a little bit is folder 'redirects' inside `/plugins` directory. Could some please help me to solve this problem (maybe someone already faced before with such kind of problem)? Or at least give some advice regarding this, e.g. maybe more efficient might be do disable wps plugin and move wp login and admin to another urls manually?

Best regards.

Comment: It is a lot of text but unclear what you are asking. Just disable the broken plugin and move on?

Comment: @RST the problem which I am trying to solve is that when we moved to https I cant get to admin dashboard anymore. In general I am asking that maybe someone already have faced with such kind of issue, and could help me. Sorry I am not native speaker so I might express idea unclearly

Comment: Rename your plugins folder (using FTP or something) and see if it works then. This is not a programming problem though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some things to verify to access to the admin dashboard.

Did you use a plugin like ReallySimpleSSL to manage the changes between http->https ?

This plugin add a piece of code in the wp-config.php and in the main htaccess.

Here is the section add that you can put in your htaccess :

```
# BEGIN rlrssslReallySimpleSSL rsssl_version[2.3.5]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

</IfModule>

# END rlrssslReallySimpleSSL

# BEGIN WordPress
```

Maybe that can make the job.

Did you correct the options `siteurl` and `home` ? 
Now that you are not able to access to the admin settings, you'll need to change it manually with phpMyAdmin or with a script in functions.php

```
function se_40436883(){

    if(get_option('rescue_se_40436883') != 1){
        update_option( 'siteurl', 'https://example.com' );
        update_option( 'home', 'https://example.com' );
        update_option( 'rescue_se_40436883', 1);
    }

}
add_action('init', 'se_40436883');
```

One another possible way is to add try to change directly some Define in the wp-config.php

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);

define('COOKIEPATH', preg_replace('|https?://[^/]+|i', '', get_option('home') . '/' ) );
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', preg_replace('|https?://[^/]+|i', '', get_option('siteurl') . '/' ) );
define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', SITECOOKIEPATH . 'wp-admin' );
```

Hope you'll get your admin back with that !

Answer (score 1):

Remove the plugin from the File directory,

/wp-content/plugins/ ..

Then install it back later..

Answer (score 1):

Rename the plugin file directory 
Rename plugins to **plugins_deactivated**
then all plugin are deactivated.

That's All you can run admin WordPress dashboard.
It's Working